# Durandal optimizer creates syntax error in app.build.js

Tags: requirejs, durandal

As I'm trying to publish my app, there is an "app.build.js" file generated which looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "durandal/amd/almond-custom",
  "inlineText": true,
  "stubModules": [
    "durandal/amd/text"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "text": "durandal/amd/text"
  },
  "include": [
    "config",
    "main-built",
    "main",
```

and so forth. I get bunch of syntax errors in this file when trying to build the project. How can I define optimizer to generate file with no syntax errors?

Final error I get is when whole project is published, main-built.js generates "ko is not defined" error.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the errors?  Which version of require.js are you using?

Comment: amd folder has almond-custom.js v0.2.0, r.js v2.1.2, require.js v2.1.2 and text.js v2.0.3. I have no idea where did optimizer.exe come from, probably added long time ago when importing Hot Towel template.

Comment: I get 2 syntax errors on ',' after blocks like "paths":{...}, and a bunch of "Expected ';'"
The main problem is that debug version is published just fine, release version when published loads main-built.js and then error pops with message: "ko is not defined". I'm not sure where to look for error, only this file actually shows errors.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, that was completely my bad, this file is working as intended even tho Resharper shows tons of errors.

I thought it was the reason my main-built.js was showing "ko is not defined" when whole project was published.

For everyone else, when building a release version, make sure your BundleConfig.cs contains non-debug versions of libraries you use. My Bundle contained only knockout-{version}.debug.js. The solution was to just add non-debug version and it all works as intended now!